# Selecting column breaks query in SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am running the following query:

```
SELECT r.id AS id 
FROM love_opt_requestor r 
JOIN love_opt_region_zips z 
WHERE z.zip = r.raw_zip_code and z.id = 27 and r.ready = 1;
```

Running this query gives me 0 results, but when I replace `SELECT r.id as id` with `SELECT r.*`, I get results.  This is true for any column that I pick.  I have verified that these columns exist and I am using the correct column name. Any ideas why selecting a column would stop the query from getting results?

EDIT: Playing around a bit, and something really funky is going on.  When I run this query

```
SELECT r.id, r.name, r.ready
FROM love_opt_requestor r 
JOIN love_opt_region_zips z 
  ON z.zip = r.raw_zip_code 
WHERE z.id = 27 AND r.id = 149411;
```

it outputs r.ready = 0.  But when I run it with `r.*`, the SAME record outputs r.ready = 1.
Even ADDING `r.*` to the `SELECT` query outputs r.ready=1

Comment: Any ideas about what kind of database and version you are using?

Comment: Can you demonstrate in a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: mysql 5.5.5-10.2.27-MariaDB

Comment: Are you viewing output directly from querying tool?

Comment: I'm viewing it on phpMyAdmin, where I'm running the query.

Answer (score 1):

How about adding an `ON` clause to the JOIN?
That would make it a valid standard SQL.
Does that help?

```
SELECT r.id
FROM love_opt_requestor r 
JOIN love_opt_region_zips z 
  ON z.zip = r.raw_zip_code 
WHERE z.id = 27
  AND r.ready = 1;
```

Comment: No, same problem

Comment: Sounds like a bug? SQL wise, there should be no reason why it returns nothing, while it does with `select *`  And there's no error?

Comment: It's not something silly like running the queries in seperate windows that are connected to different databases with same tables, but  not same content?

Comment: No, only one window, one db, etc.

Comment: I wonder if there's something corrupt in a table or index. Maybe try [OPTIMIZE TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30065747/4003419) to rebuild indexes and analyze?