# MySql Match() Against FA not search

Tags: mysql

I'm not able to figure it out why this is not working.

Here is my query which works:

```
SELECT *
FROM mshop_supplier
WHERE MATCH (mshop_supplier.keyword) AGAINST ('FA' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY mshop_supplier.id DESC;
```

I set up some settings to solve this,
it is set `innodb_ft_min_token_size=2` and `innodb_ft_enable_stopword=OFF`

But didn't work it, can you tell me why

When I search with `where mshop_supplier.keyword like %FA%`, there's data

Comment: Does the variables names were set before the FTS index creation? if not then you must recreate it.

Comment: Also %FA% search matches more cases than the fullyext search for FA.

Answer (score 0):

When you change the `innodb_ft_min_token_size` setting you need to rebuild the fulltext index, as mentioned in [12.9.6 Fine-Tuning MySQL Full-Text Search - Configuring Minimum and Maximum Word Length](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length):

> After changing any of these options, rebuild your `FULLTEXT` indexes
> for the change to take effect. For example, to make two-character
> words searchable, you could put the following lines in an option file:
>
> ```
> [mysqld]
> innodb_ft_min_token_size=2
> ft_min_word_len=2
> ```
>
> Then restart the server and rebuild your `FULLTEXT` indexes.

Check [How can I rebuild indexes and update stats in MySQL innoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30051510/how-can-i-rebuild-indexes-and-update-stats-in-mysql-innodb) on how to rebuild the index after you have changed the settings.